# xlwings' RunPython fails on MAC

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlwings

```
    MAC 10.12.5  
    Excel 2011 for MAC 
    xlwings.__version__ '0.11.2'
xlwings.__path__
['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlwings']
```

Trying to do a RunPython from excel, always fails with:

```
Compile Error
Connot find file or library
```

Trying to narrow down, running the VBA code found in 
Function GetConfigFilePath() As String), specifically:

```
> mymodule = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
```

invariably gives me a:

```
Compile Error
Connot find file or library
```

I see that the

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/xlwings.conf
```

could not be found but i have no idea how to get it there, any lead please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: v0.11.4 supports Mac Excel 2011 again, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-11-4-jul-23-2017

Make sure to check that it references the correct xlwings addin: In the VBA editor, go to `Tools > References` and select `xlwings`. Unselect those that start with `MISSSING...`. Make sure the correct project is selected while you do this.

original answer:

Mac Excel 2011 support hasn't quite caught up with the new add-in. The issues is that Excel 2011 doesn't show the ribbon and so the config file will not be created automatically. We will work on improving the user experience, but for now you should be able to work around it like this:

- Create an empty `xlwings.conf` in the following path (you'll need to create it if you don't have Excel 2016 installed) `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data`
- Edit it following the instructions, if you want to set global settings that deviate from the defaults: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#config-file
- Alternatively, skip the 2 steps above and include a `xlwings.conf` sheet as created automatically by `xlwings quickstart <projectname>`, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#workbook-settings (you need to use the addin from >= 0.11.3 though as there was a bug in the earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks It is some progess. 

However, in the sample code provided with the quickstart xlwings:
> - mymodule = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, 
     (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
fails... VBA does not know "Left".  I removed that line.
> - RunPython ("import test7;test7.hello_xlwings()") fails with message: 
Complie Error: cannot find project or library
It might be because in the terminal: xlwings runpython install   
gives me:
Successfully installed RunPython for Mac Excel 2016!
(tough luck i am on excel 2011!).  Any idea how to install for 2011?

Comment: `xlwings runpython install` is only needed for Mac Excel 2016, it doesn't have an effect for 2011.

Comment: You need to wait for 0.11.4, there were still a few things missing for Excel 2011. I will update my answer once released.

Comment: Thanks Felix.   
A few items of note:

>1. xlwings quickstart project1:  

>>1a. mymodule = Left(...)     Leads a message from excel: "Compile Error: cannot find project or library".

>>1b. Same  with directly ref:  "RunPython" fails, same message.   

>2. xlwings quickstart project2 --standalone:  
Works fine in all cases (direct and not direct ref)    

>3. Finally, in the xlwings.conf, you may want to change the Interpreter "pythonw" 
to "/usr/local/bin/python3".  

I hope this will help other users to put this interesting module to good use.

Comment: @CyBu you will need to make sure it has the reference to your xlwings addin: in the VBA editor, go to `Tools > References`, then select xlwings und deselect anything that's marked with `MISSING...`